# Meaning of ./main command in terminal

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, command-line-interface

I am working with [this](https://github.com/tomsmeding/editor) c++ project for making command line text editor like Vim. The documentation tells that in order to run this text editor in terminal you need to write command `./main` in the project folder.

The project folder has main.cpp file. Is this a command to execute that file (may be I am wrong) or this command is a standard terminal command.

Thank you.

Comment: `./` indicates it is in this folder. `main` is the name of the executable (which a .cpp file is not), so `./main` executes an executable called `main` in the current folder.

Comment: This is not a question about programming, I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: This is clearly **not** a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Running `./main` means run `main` from the *current directory* (`.`).

The *current directory* is normally missing from `$PATH` so you have to specify it explicitly.

Comment: can you please tell what is $PATH. And why do we need to specify any path as I can execute from any location. ( Please bear with me as I am newbie in programming ).

Comment: Sorry but not knowing what `$PATH` is makes you a newbie as a user, not a programmer.